# Trying to get the value of a Redis key in laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I use Redis for my Cache in laravel.

In my codebase, I have a piece of code which sets a cache value like this:

```
$key = 'track:' . $user->id ...; // this value comes out as 'track:2697:08169'
Cache::put($key, $value, $expiry);
```

So at this point, the key is `'track:2697:08169'` and the value is `10`, and if I were to run `Cache::get('track:2697:08169')` I would naturally get 10 out.

I've been trying to dig into the internals for reasons I'll not go into, but I was trying to find all the keys in my cache, `Redis::connection('cache')->keys('*');`, and this particular key showed up in the list as `myapi_database_myapi_cache:track:2697:08169`. Did a little research to discover that the `Cache` facade uses a prefix for these scenarios, makes sense to me.

So naturally, if that's the key according to Redis, then I should be able to do this: `Redis::connection('cache')->get('myapi_database_myapi_cache:track:2697:08169');`

But that doesn't give me anything. It's just blank.

Why can I access the value via the Cache:: facade, but not by Redis directly using the prefixed key? How can I access the value for this key? Also, is there any way to access the expiry of this key?

Comment: check the redis-cli as well e.g. `redis-cli get myapi_cache:track:2697:08169`

Comment: @apokryfos i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer by messing around a bit. I left out some vital information in my question, I didn't think it would be relevant, sorry for that.

I said that my key `Cache::get('track:2697:08169')` got turned into `'myapi_cache:track:2697:08169'`, but that's not true -- it got turned into `'myapi_database_myapi_cache:track:2697:08169'`, and therein was the source of my issues:

When I was doing `Redis::connection('cache')->get('myapi_database_myapi_cache:track:2697:08169');` it wasn't working, and when I was doing `Redis::connection('cache')->get('track:2697:08169');` it wasn't working either, but I played around and discovered that `Redis::connection('cache')->get('myapi_cache:track:2697:08169');` actually does work!

Once I changed the key by removing that part of the prefix, but not the `myapi_cache` prefix, this worked too: `$ttl = Redis::connection('cache')->ttl($rediskey);`